# Always check spelling before sending email keeps becoming disabled

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'm running Windows 8.1 with Office Professional 2010.
A "Windows" update was recently installed on my machine and the Outlook settings to check spelling before sending an email became disabled.
I've changed the default settings back to check "*Always check spelling before sending*" emails numerous times but the setting continuously defaults back to NOT checking the emails before they are sent.

Comment: Hi Scott.  Does it revert immediately, or does it take a while before it gets disabled again?  Is this your personal computer, or a company-supplied one?

Comment: The computer I'm experiencing the issues on is my personal computer.  It doesn't happen immediately; it takes some time.  I haven't had the time yet to try and pinpoint the sequence of events that cause it to happen (machine reboot, time duration, etc)

Comment: It appears that each time I exit the program (MS Outlook) the boxes becomes unchecked.  I did not have to reboot the computer...just exiting the program triggered the change.

Comment: Very weird.  if you uninstall the Windows Update that's your suspect, does the functionality return to normal?

Comment: Yes, very weird.  I also noticed that the reading pane preference changes as well as the option to use Ctrl Enter to send an email.  There are 48 updates associated with the most recent round.

Comment: That happens when you're such a bad speller that it would overwhelm the system to keep up with the corrections.  It disables the spell checker to avoid a BSOD.  :-)

Comment: I have the opposite problem - that damn setting keeps coming back on! (every time a windows update is applied it seems to come back on)